# How to prevent compilation if an error status is ignored?

Tags: c++, exception, error-code

During his [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NOCElcMcFik) at cppcon, Titus Winters states (at 42:00) that they have a [Status](http://google.github.io/google-api-cpp-client/latest/doxygen/util_2status_8h_source.html) class. What is magic about that class is that a C++ build is supposed to fail if a `Status` object is returned and nothing is done to it (Note that it is possible to explicitely call `IgnoreError()` if this is the correct thing to do).

**How is such a thing possible?**

As far as I can tell, the `Status` class has nothing very special. I suppose they have to hack that rule into their build process but how can one do that?

Comment: it is not possible to do what you explained (failing a build if the object is not used, without calling it's method)

Comment: You can clearly see in the code you've linked to that that `Status` class bundles an `enum` and `std::string` and the destructor and `IgnoreError()` functions' implementations do nothing - no magic lies therein - so if there's any enforcement it must be in some static analysis tool Google's running over their code during the builds... not through Standard C++ features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is now the **[[nodiscard]]** attribute to do that.

Some more info:

- [C++ Weekly episode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l_5PF3GQLKc&feature=youtu.be)
- [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes)